# Alternar ejecución de dos funciones en el tiempo

Tags: python

Quiero alternar en el tiempo la ejecución de dos funciones de forma continua.

El siguiente diagrama de secuencia muestra una idea de lo que quiero llevar a cabo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A fin de evitar una "chapuza" como puede ser un bucle while(True) utilizando time.sleep() mi primera aprximación en Python ha sido utilizar la opción threaring.Timer. A continuación muestro un código de ejemplo:

```
import threading 

delayOff = 2
delayOn = 0.5
counter = 0

def tOn():

        #Acciones en estado tOn  
        #.
        #.
        #.

        global counter
        counter+=1
        print("Estoy en On - counter = " + str(counter))

        #Timers
        timer_on = threading.Timer(delayOn,tOff)

        #Start the timers
        timer_on.start()     



def tOff():

        #Acciones en estado tOff  
        #.
        #.
        #.

        global counter
        counter+=1
        print("Estoy en Off - counter = " + str(counter))

        #Timers
        timer_off = threading.Timer(delayOff,tOn)
        #Start the timers
        timer_off.start() 



#Iniciamos la serie llamando a tOn
tOn()
```

Que otras alternativas existen?
Cuales son los pros y contras de esta solución?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola David, si la ejecución de las funciones es alterna pero no requieres concurrencia, usar iteración mediante un ciclo no creo que sea para nada una chapuza, es más legible y sobretodo considerablemente más eficiente al evitar el despliegue constante de hilos.

Comment: En el fondo lo que busco es algo parecido a un timer que me vaya disparando "eventos" cada x segundos. Entonces realizar ciertas acciones (por eso las funciones) cada vez que se dispara el evento. PD: LO el wjile (True) lo quería evitar para no bloquear el hilo principal. Muchas gracias,  FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todavía no tengo privilegios para "comentar" tu pregunta, así que te respondo por aquí:

Sin ser un experto en el tema, diría que como alternativas tienes la libreria `asyncio` para ejecutar funciones de forma asíncrona sin pringarte con el multithreading, que es bastante más complicado de mantener.

También depende de lo que necesites conseguir. Demorar y delegar la ejecución de funciones por una razón de tiempo tiene sentido como prueba de concepto, pero a no ser que lo necesites forzosamente yo preferiría controlar el flujo del programa a razón del estado de las funciones que estas ejecutando.

El propósito de usar varios "hilos" es que se ejecuten al mismo tiempo, no detenerlos para ejecutar otro, que en ese caso es lo que hace la libreria `asyncio`, o como comenta @FJSevilla con un `while()` evaluando un delta de tiempo de entrada y salida (ej. `while(tiempo_ahora < tiempo_ahora + tiempo_delay`) para cada función y ejecutarlas secuencialmente dentro de otro bucle. No sería del todo "chapucero", pero en términos pythonicos sería cuanto menos extraño o inusual. No escribimos codigo así por estos valles :)

Espero que te guie un poco esta información en lo que buscas.